# Reversing a string in C using Recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I have written a program to reverse a string using recursion. But the output I get is an empty string always.

I want to know what is wrong with my logic?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse(char a[], int start, int end)
{
    char t;
    if(start>=end)
        return;
    else
    {
        t = a[start]; a[start] = a[end]; a[end] = t;
        reverse(a,++start,--end);   
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); 
    printf("Given string is : %s ",a);
    reverse(a,0,n-1);
    printf("Reversed string is : %s ",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

[image]

Printing the individual characters I get,

[image]

Comment: Why would you ever want to use recursion for this? The program was too fast? Consumed too little memory? Source code too readable?

Comment: Lundin: This could be homework or simply him trying to learn a bit about recursion with a simple functionn.

Comment: @hugomg Good, then he can forward my questions to his teacher. Or sum them up as "Why are you teaching bad programming practice?"

Comment: One small suggestion: If I were you I would have used `start+1` and `end-1` instead of `++` and `--`. The variable mutations are unnecessary and only serve to confuse things.

Comment: @Lundin I have started learning the basics of recursion and trying a few programs on my own. So I had a doubt with that.

Comment: Well, just note that unless you are learning binary search and other such computer algorithms, there is really no need to ever use or understand recursion. In fact, recursion has very limited real use and is one of the most overrated features of C. It is an obscure legacy feature from assembler and C beginners tend to spend far too much time pondering over it. And because they spent so much time on it when they were students, they get tempted to use it later on in their programming career, creating Toyotas that run amok with stack overflow, killing people...

Comment: @Lumen That reasoning is the root of many programming mistakes. _C programming != mathematical theory_. _All_ recursion can be replaced with loops, aka "unrolling". The only cases where you actually can justify it, is algorithms where recursion actually improves readability AND where readability is paramount to program speed, program safety and memory consumption. Binary search/sort algorithms on a PC computer is one such example.

Comment: @Lundin trees use recursion completely and so too dynamic programming.  So to get the basics right I am learning recursion first then I will move to divide and conquer algorithmic strategy then dynamic programming and finally trees.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your string is actually 6 bytes long - `'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'`. The last character is a null byte, which is a string terminator. It signals to functions like `printf` or `strlen` where the string ends. When you call `reverse`, it reverses the entire string, so now the terminator is the very first byte, and `printf` interprets that as an empty string.

There are two ways to fix this. Either make the index that you pass to `reverse` one smaller (call `reverse(a, 0, n-2)`), or use `strlen` instead of `sizeof` (`int n = strlen(a)`).

Comment: That was the mistake. I didn't consider the null character. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always remember, the array index for `n`th element will be `n-1`.

Your array has 6 elements, so the index will run from `0` to `5`, the last [6th] elemst being the `NUL` terminator.

As per your logic, the `NUL` terminator becomes the first element in the reversed array, hence no output as `string`.

Following the logic, your first call to `reverse()` should be `reverse(a,0,n-2);` to avoid the `NUL` being put as the first element in reversed array.

Comment: That was the mistake. I didn't consider the null character. Thanks